Cannot Connect to MongoDB Atlas from GCP Cloud Run Instance
I followed this guide to creating a static outbound IP and attaching it to the instance. I have confirmed that the outbound IP is correctly setup and that outbound requests are from that IP by using this quick snippet:
const response = await axios.get('https://ipinfo.io/ip');
const externalIP = response.data.trim();
console.log(`Outbound External IP Address: ${externalIP}`);

I also confirmed that the logged IP is exactly the same as the IP whitelisted for the database. However, I'm still unable to connect. As with Mongoose, there aren't very descriptive errors for connection errors, so I'm just getting the SSL handshake failed error. Any ideas?
EDIT 1:
Here is how I am connecting to the cluster:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

let connection;
const connect = async () => {
  try {
    connection = await mongoose.connect(uri, {
      bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
    });
    return connection;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Could not connect to MongoDB...");
    throw e;
  }
};

function getConnection() {
  return connection;
}

module.exports = { connect, getConnection };

And here is the error:
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist

error: MongoNetworkError: 08123BD0DA3E0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80


Edit your question and show how you are connecting, the MongoDB configuration, and the exact error. Typically, an SSL handshake error means that you did connect to something, but not necessarily the correct host. Also, your instance's IP address is not causing that error.

Can you share how you build your container? Did you install the SSL binaries on it?

@JohnHanley The MongoDB configuration is fairly straight forward. I'm able to connect fine when allowing all IPs, but not when I only allow the static outbound IP. I'm guessing there's something I'm missing in the network configuration that is causing this. I may have to go a different route instead of a static outbound IP.

@guillaumeblaquiere There's nothing special about the build of the container, just a simple docker file. As noted in my previous comment, it is definitely network related as the image runs fine and the connection works fine when allowing all IPs

Have you considered using certificates to authenticate users instead of IP whitelisting? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/

You can also use PSC (or VPC peering) and internal connectivity without any whitelisting

It appears that you might have a TLS protocol error or a memory allocation failure. What is the code running on? What is the MONGODB_URI? You can mangle the URI a little bit to mask but I want to see that the connection string is correct. If you whitelist all IP addresses does the connection work? Is your system low on free memory? Another possibility is that your app is connecting with a TLS protocol version that MongoDB does not support. For example, connecting with TLS 1.0 which is disabled by default in MongoDB.

@JohnHanley Thank you for the suggestion. Usually you would use certificates instead of credentials for authentication in addition to IP whitelisting, so that's not an ideal solution. The MONGODB_URI is correct. When allowing all IPs, I am able to connect to the cluster. I'll try using VPC peering instead.

VPC Peering will not help you if the instance is public.

Hi this is just another suggestion.
You can attempt to establish a connection by utilizing private IP access from Cloud Run to the MongoDB Atlas cluster. This configuration ensures that MongoDB connects exclusively through private IP addresses. This configuration will use VPC peering.
First you need to create a VPC serverless access connector, make sure when you create this, your region should match the serverless service. Use a custom IP range and configure a private IP range with /28 mask.
Note that this configuration in MongoDB Atlas cluster uses Dedicated Cluster for VPC network peering. Under MongoDB atlas access list, in the security section click Network access then add IP address. In the Access list entry, you may enter the /28 private ip address that you created under the VPC access connector.
Next is to configure the MongoDB Atlas VPC peering. You may use this documentation for guidelines.
To peer, the next is to create VPC peering on GCP. Enter the project ID and VPC network name that were provided to configured MongoDB Atlas VPC peering.
Below is a screenshot of the next step that is needed to do. For a detailed instruction of this suggestion you may visit this link


To anyone wondering, this worked much better than a static outbound IP
